# php ffmpeg converting to formats used by html5 video

Tags: php, ffmpeg, html5-video, ogg, webm

Can someone post list here for conversing commands for ffmpeg to make all formats for html5 video in php, here is the ones I use now:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i ' .$tmpName. ' upload/' .$newName. '.mp4');
exec('ffmpeg -i ' .$tmpName. ' -acodec libvorbis -vcodec libvpx upload/' .$newName. '.webm');
exec('ffmpeg -i' .$tmpName. ' -acodec vorbis -vcodec libtheora  upload/' .$newName. '.ogv');
exec('ffmpeg -i ' .$tmpName. ' -acodec vorbis -aq 100 upload/' .$newName. '.ogg');
```

Before it was doing converting for mp4, ogv and ogg, and didn't do for webm, and then I ask them to update ffmpeg on server, and they update it, so now only mp4 works...

If I write:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i ' .$tmpName. ' upload/' .$newName. '.webm');
```

It creates new file with 0 bytes size...

This is the info they send me about this update:

```
[root@web ffmpeg]# ffmpeg -formats|awk '/mp4/||/ogg/||/ogv/||/webm/'

ffmpeg version git-N-29495-g749d16c, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
 built on Apr 29 2011 02:22:31 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)
 configuration: --prefix=/usr
 libavutil    51.  1. 0 / 51.  1. 0
 libavcodec   53.  1. 1 / 53.  1. 1
 libavformat  53.  0. 3 / 53.  0. 3
 libavdevice  53.  0. 0 / 53.  0. 0
 libavfilter   2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
 libswscale    0. 14. 0 /  0. 14. 0
 D  matroska,webm   Matroska/WebM file format
 D  mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 QuickTime/MPEG-4/Motion JPEG 2000 format
 E mp4             MP4 format
 DE ogg             Ogg
 E webm            WebM file format
```

I can't believe that there is no complete list for all of those conversions online that is working... I search through everywhere and I can't find right one...

Can someone make this working?

Thank you!

Comment: Given that version number, it would appear they pulled a nightly development build, and those are NOT guaranteed to work.  The most recent official releases are 0.6.3 final and 0.7rc1

Comment: So it's because of version?
Also, here is not mentioned that avi files can be converted...

Can you write me codes like this used for converting to formats that is supported by <video> html5 formats ( ogg, webm and mp4 ) like I write in my question examples?
I found bunch of codes from net and none of those aren't working okay... :/

Comment: AVI files are a container. If we were dealing with food, then AVIs are the tupperware container to the video's food. ffmpeg can certainly parse the AVI container structure, but whether it can handle actual video data depends on what codec was used to create that video.

Comment: Okay... Thank you! :)
So problem with this is that version is beta, and that it's not working okay?

Comment: No idea, but that's a likely reason. A nightly build doesn't even qualify as 'beta'. Beta means it's stable and in testable shape. Nightly is generally whatever state it was in when the last person leaves the office at night. It might compile, it might not. You never know.